# Need a shell script which should send a mail to me once every 20 days

Tags: shell-script

Can some one tell me the logic or the entire script to create a shell script to send a mail to me once every 20 days

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email

Answer (score 3):

If it's just a mail with text, no attachments:

/some/path/script.sh

Content:

```
#send me an email:
cat text | mail -s "subject" your@email.com
```

To have it every 20 days, a way could be to change to script to add :

```
#send me an email:
cat text | mail -s "subject" your@email.com
#and the script itself re-schedule itself to start again in 20 days:
echo "$0" | at now + 20 days #And remember to launch that script using its full path
```

Another way could be to use crontabs (`crontab -e` as the user you want the script to be run with). To run the script every 20 days via crontab, I let you `man crontab` ^^

If you need attachments in that mail, better install "mutt" (or similar programs easy to use in the command line, and able to handle attachments).

===

another approach now that you precised you want to use a daily cron: 
You run a script every day, and want it to do something special (ie, send an email) if it has been 20 days?

a way would be to have this sections inside that script:

```
#the script

#near the beginning:
[ ! -e /some/flagfile ] && touch /some/flagfile #create /some/flagfile, ONCE.

...  #the usual script treatment, if any

#and the test: if our flagfile is >=20 days old, we mail a msg and delete the flag
sleep 10  #IMPORTANT: that way we are sure the flag done 20 days ago is at least
          #           20days+a few seconds, and thus the following test will work !
if ( find /some -mtime +20 -print | grep '/some/flagfile$' >/dev/null )
then
     # we found a /some/flagfile of at least 20 days!
    cat /some/message | mail -s "subject" your@email.com
    rm /some/flagfile  #you could add checks that the email worked...
     # so next time you run the script, it will create the new /some/flagfile.
     # But if you prefer to have the 20 days start "now" instead of when the script
     # is run next, you could uncomment the next line instead:
    #touch /some/flagfile
fi

...
```

Comment: Need a script which i can schedule that script in cron to run every day and see if its 20th day, it'll send a mail to me.. Hope you understand my question now..

Comment: @user50177: I updated my answer: see the "other approach"

Answer (score 2):

If the computer you run this on is never switched off, you could just launch a little script like this:

```
while :; do sleep 20d; echo "hello Bob" | mail -s "subject" your@email.com; done
```

The script above will run for ever (`while :;`), it will wait for 20 days (sleep 20d), then send you a mail then wait for another 20 days, send you the mail again etc.

Another approach which is ugly but should work is to generate the cron lines manually then add them to your crontab:

```
DATE=$(date -d "$(date -d @"$(($(date +%s) + 1728000))")")
for i in {1..16}; do 
 DATE=$(date -d "$(date -d @"$(( $(date -d "$DATE" +%s) + 1728000))")" +"%e %b");
 echo "0 0 $DATE echo \"hello bob\" | mail you@email.com"
done
```

Running the script above produces the following output:

```
0 0  8 Dec echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 28 Dec echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 17 Jan echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0  6 Feb echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 26 Feb echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 18 Mar echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0  7 Apr echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 27 Apr echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 17 May echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0  6 Jun echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 26 Jun echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 16 Jul echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0  5 Aug echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 25 Aug echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0 14 Sep echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
0 0  4 Oct echo "hello bob" | mail you@email.com
```

Adding those lines to your crontab will cause an email to be sent to you every 20 days for the next year. You'll have to run it again next year.

Comment: I think that's going to run every 30-ish days, on the 20th. Or maybe the 1st and 20th. But I'm pretty sure it won't be every 20 days.

Comment: @derobert I know `*/5` in the first field will run every 5 minutes, why would the days field be different? Also, unless I misunderstand the man page that is exactly what it says it will do: "every two hours", just use "*/2".

Comment: I haven't tested, but */5 means 0,5,10... That works out since 60 is a multiple of 5. Similarly, */20 would mean 0,20,40 in a minutes or seconds field, where it'd work (60 being a multiple of 20), but it should mean the same thing in the day-of-month field, but it won't work there as 28, 29, 30, and 31 are not multiples of 20.

Comment: @derobert dammit, you're absolutely right, thanks. Answer changed.

Comment: Hah, I think you ought to still mention cron—you can (mostly) do every 20 days, with more entries, by spelling out jan 1, jan 21, feb 10, mar 2 (1st on a leap year), etc. Or by running daily and using `date +%j` (neither are perfect, as 365/366 are not multiples of 20). Or stunts with `find -mtime +20`.

Comment: @derobert better?

Comment: Better! Wow that's a scary `date ...` command... I guess `date -d "2013-01-01 + 20 days"` is a GNU-ism...

Comment: @derobert Ummm yes, that is _exactly_ why I did not use it :). I think it _is_ a GNUism actually but I simply did not know that date can do that so I used seconds. And yes, it is scary, and incomprehensible :)